# Telegraf OPC-UA and InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, opc-ua, telegraf, kepserverex

I get data from KepServer OPC UA in to the InfluxDB via telegraf. When machine is turned off for a few hours I get errors:

```
2023-07-06T07:03:47Z E! [inputs.opcua_listener] status not OK for node Torque_Av_LidHead:  Bad (0x80000000)
2023-07-06T07:27:37Z E! [inputs.opcua_listener] status not OK for node Torque_Av_LidHead:  Bad (0x80000000)
2023-07-06T11:04:27Z E! [inputs.opcua_listener] status not OK for node Torque_Av_LidHead:  Bad (0x80000000)
```

and after turn on machine telegraf doesn't log data in to the InfluxDB, and it is working only after telegraf restart.

What i need:

If machine is turned on from off telegraf automatically grabbing the data from KepServer OPC-UA.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgrade telegraf to 1.27.1 and working fine.